# button setHidden crashed in iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, crash, uibutton, exc-bad-access

everyone. I added a button in a view and set it to be hidden under certain condition. While it crashes only the first time I load the whole project in iOS5. After the first time, it runs well. Xcode gives me no more information except Thread1... I wonder if anyone could help. Thanks in forward.

Here's some of the code.

testView.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *testBtn;
```

testView.m

```
@synthesize testBtn;

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        testBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)layoutSubviews{
        testBtn.frame = CGRectMake(110, 100, 100, 24);
        [testBtn setHidden:YES];
        [self addSubview: testBtn];
}
```

testViewController.m

```
-(void)requestForSth{
       [testView.testBtn setHidden:NO];   //Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x809a3345)
}
```

Comment: @PraveenS  It's just a common UIView.

Comment: My guess would be that your testView isn't allocated at the time you try to access its property.
Make sure your testView is a valid object before calling "requestForSth"

Comment: You shouldn't be adding subviews in `-layoutSubviews`.

Comment: @Maggie I do have allocated testView in ViewDidLoad of testViewController. And I wonder why it's only the first time loading when it crashes...

Comment: @JacobRelkin I guess it's ok... and why do you think so?

Comment: @Lilac Because it's a *layout* method and therefore called frequently - it's not meant to be used for tinkering with the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means that you tried to access invalid memory. 
In your `-init` method, you are assigning `testBtn` to an *autoreleased* `UIButton` object.

I believe that if this file were compiled without ARC, this makes sense. 
Why? Because ownership semantics don't apply when you perform direct assignment. Only by way of your **setter method** will the correct ownership semantics be applied.

Under ARC, this is solved thanks to a `__strong` ownership qualifier by default. If you're still adamant about not moving to ARC, then you can simply `retain` your `UIButton` before assigning it directly into your instance variable.

Taking a closer look at your code:

```
- (id)init {
   self = [super init];
   if(self) {
      //you can explicitly retain it
      testBtn = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
      //or route it through your setter method
      [self setTestBtn:[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]];
   }
   return self;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if I get you correctly, but I retain testButton in my -init and it does stop crashing. However, testView seems to be hidden only when the first time this project is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I got you. Yeah, I just retained testBtn as the way your first solution did. But testView is totally black when loading after I change layoutSubviews into viewDidLoad...